# Changing one character in a char* array without converting to char[][]

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

I have a one-dimensional array of string literals of different lengths like so:

```
char *map[] = {
"ABC",
"ABCDEF",
...
};
```

I would like to change a certain character in the array with `map[y][x]='X';`, which does not (and should not) work according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault#Writing_to_read-only_memory). I also read that declaring it as `char map[][]` would fix the bug. However, this is a VERY large array so converting it to `char map[][]` will be impractical. Is there another way to accomplish what I want?

Comment: if you don't mind wasting a bit of space, I would go with the answer by @VladfromMoscow. It's the easiest way to migrate your code.

Comment: @RSahu, Vlad's answer works, but printing the array also prints out some garbage (when printing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h> 

#define CNV(x) (char []){ x }

int main(void){
    char *map[] = {
    CNV("ABC"),
    CNV("ABCDEF"),
    //...
    };
    map[1][2]='c';
    printf("%s\n", map[1]);//ABcDEF
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: This is actually better than Vlad's answer as it allows me to print it

Answer (score 2):

You may not change string literals. They are immutable in C/C++.

The more correct your definition of the array would look as

```
const char *map[] = {
"ABC",
"DEF",
...
};
```

You have to use a two-dimensional character array that to be able to change its elements.

For example

```
char map[][4] = {
    "ABC",
    "DEF",
    ...
    };
```

Or you could use the array of pointers changing the required element by assigning a new string literal to it.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the strings are of different lengths.

Comment: @theunamedguy See my updated post. Take into account that there is no difference whether you store strings in an array or you store pointers to string literals if all string literals are different.

Comment: However, when I try to print it, it also prints some garbage.

Comment: @theunamedguy You did not specify the left-most size of the array. It has to be large enough that to accomodate each string literal includding its terminating zero. See the definition of the two-dimensional array in my post. You should substitute value 4 for the actual size of the maximum string literal.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to change the strings contained in your array you are going to have to work with dynamically allocated memory. I would allocate an array of `char*` and then run through and allocate memory for each followed by a call to `strncpy`, or similar.

```
char** ptrArray = malloc(sizeof(char*)*NUM_STRINGS); 
...
ptrArray[0] = malloc(sizeof(someString)*sizeof(char));
strncpy(ptrArray[0], someString, sizeof(someString));
```

It really depends on the context of your application.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is by definition `1`.

Comment: This would work, but would require the entire array to be initialized at startup.

Comment: I always tend to put it in there. I understand what a char is, but I did not realize it was standard across all compilers in that way. I had never encountered `sizeof(char) > 1`, but just in case I suppose I always included it.

Comment: @theunamedguy, it depends on the context of your application. You can always `realloc` if you need more (or less if you're careful) strings. Allocating memory for each pointer and copying the data can be done at anytime of course.

Comment: @sherrellbc: `sizeof` fundamentally measures in units of `char`. Evaluating `sizeof(char)` is like asking "how many meters are there in a meter?"

Comment: Even more interesting! Yet another bit of trivia I was not aware of. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is an array of pointers to strings which are located in a read-only memory section:

```
char* map[] =
{
    "ABC",
    "DEF",
    ...
};
```

You can change the value of each pointer, but you cannot change the contents of the pointed memory.

---

This is an array of pointers to strings which are located in a read/write memory section:

```
char map[][MAX_STR_LEN+1] =
{
    "ABC",
    "DEF",
    ...
};
```

You cannot change the value of each pointer, but you can change the contents of the pointed memory.

---

Please note that in the second scheme, you have basically two options:

1. Declare the array as a global variable, in which case it will reside in the data-section of the executable image and loaded into memory along with it (i.e., no initialization code executed).
2. Declare the array as a local variable, in which case the function will include an additional piece of code for initializing the array every time it is called (copying all the strings from the RO-data-section into the stack).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

char s1[] = "abcd";
char s2[] = "efghi";
char s3[] = "jklmnop";

char *s[] = {
  s1, s2, s3
};

int main(void)
{
  s[0][0] = '$';
  printf("%s %s %s\n", s[0], s[1], s[2]);
  return 0;
}
```

Edit: the above code replaces the pointer to strings by pointer to (writable) arrays of characters, resulting in the desired writable behavior.